# What piece of code am I missing in this python code? Adding digits together

Tags: python, join, addition

I have this code with input for example of 34, 56 and supposed output of 28,46.  However, what I am getting as output is: 24, 4, 40,6 (24+4 = 28 and 40 + 6 = 46). Question is, what line of code am I missing?

```
def decode(code):
    decimals = []
    code = code.split(" ")
    for number in code:
        length = len(number)
        for digit in number:
            decimal = int(digit) * (8**(length - 1))
            decimals.append(decimal)
            length -= 1
    print(decimals)
```

Comment: please provide complete information on how are you calling this function, or how you need to input those values

Answer (score 2):

You forget that you must add the numbers back again. A solution for it:

```
def decode(code):
        decimals = []
        code = code.split(" ")
        for number in code:
            length = len(number)
            decimal = 0
            for digit in number:
                decimal += int(digit) * (8**(length - 1))
                length -= 1
            decimals.append(decimal)
        print(decimals)
```

Edit: When you want, to print it as "28 46", then change the code, above to:

```
def decode(code):
    decimals = ''
    code = code.split(" ")
    for number in code:
        length = len(number)
        decimal = 0
        for digit in number:
            decimal += int(digit) * (8 ** (length - 1))
            length -= 1
        decimals += " "+str(decimal)
    print(decimals)
```

Comment: or do I have to add a return statement something like.... eg  return str(' '.join(decimals))  (although that comes up with errors...

Comment: ooh, thanks. Now I am getting [28, 46] as a result but want "28 46" - I guess I'm missing a string somewhere?

Comment: @catcoder7 Do you want a List or a String to get printed? In your Code you also get a List as output.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the concept that each number in the result needs to be the sum of its digits. I would add another list:

```py
def decode(code):
    results = []
    code = code.split(" ")
    for number in code:
        length = len(number)
        decimals = []
        for digit in number:
            decimal = int(digit) * (8**(length - 1))
            decimals.append(decimal)
            length -= 1
        results.append(str(sum(decimals)))
    print(results)
    return ' '.join(results)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am still missing something as I now have [28, 46] being returned rather than "28 46" .  I'm a newbie - can't figure it out!

Comment: But you said you wanted: `"supposed output of 28,46"`. Do you, in fact, want a string returned?

Comment: at the mo, it's printing out [28,46].  And the helper file wants "28 46".  As a newbie, I'm thinking they are expecting a string?

Comment: eg Test 8. Input = "34 56" Output = "28 46" 
[28, 46]
 Failed!

Comment: I'll update my answer to provide a string.